# Ai Platform Prediction storage bucket trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-ai-platform

My when the user selects an image on my ios app, i want that image to upload to a storage bucket, run my tf model on that image-outputtng another image, then save this output image to the cloud bucket aswell.

Shall I use cloud function with a trigger on uploading to the storage bucket, then call my ai platform prediction model from the cloud function, then use the cloud function to save the output image?

Or is there a way I can skip the cloud function and only use ai platform prediction with custom prediction routine. Then in postprocessing upload output image to my storage bucket. I'm not sure that I can trigger the ai platform prediction from uploading to a storage bucket though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could imagine to [sink the Cloud Storage event (the image upload event) into PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications), create a push subscription on PubSub and then to create a custom prediction routine that accept PubSub message format, recover the file content from Cloud Storage and perform the prediction.

You also can imagine to implement, in the custom routine, the storage of the output in Cloud Storage.

---

However, I don't recommend that. Your prediction service is too sticky to Cloud Storage and PubSub, and it has too many responsibilities. To use Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to handle the events is a better and more scalable/evolution capable design.

Comment: Thank you, I will stick to the latter